# Why does my code work for only first tr in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
jQuery("#contentItems table.tablesorter tbody tr td:eq(3)").live('mousedown', function (e) {
        var tr = jQuery(this);
        tr.fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
});
```

Basically, I want the 4th cell in each row in my table to fade out a bit, when I click on them. But the above code only seems to work for the first tr's 4th cell. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with `delegate`

```
$("#contentItems table.tablesorter tbody tr").delegate('td:eq(3)', 'mousedown', function(e){
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
});
```

Or this using `nth-child` selector which is 1 index based

```
$("#contentItems table.tablesorter tbody tr td:nth-child(4)").live('mousedown', function(e){
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`:eq(3)` matches exactly the 3rd `td` regardless of whether you specify the tr as the ancestor.  You want to use the `nth-child` selector instead.  I also recommend that you use `delegate` because it is much faster and cleaner:

See http://jsfiddle.net/At4bW/

Answer (score 0):

The why is `#contentItems table.tablesorter tbody tr td` will match all `td` in all rows in your table, then the `:eq(3)` will match the fouth `td` in that set.

Try this instead:

```
jQuery("#contentItems table.tablesorter tbody tr")
    .delegate("td:eq(3)", 'mousedown', function () {
        var tr = jQuery(this);
        tr.fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
    }
);
```

Comment: So how do I apply the eq() to only the td instead of the entire select?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery("#contentItems table.tablesorter tbody tr").each(jQuery("td:eq(3)", this).live('mousedown', function (e) {
     var tr = jQuery(this);
     tr.fadeTo('fast', 0.5);
 }))
```

This will apply the inner jQuery selector (grab the 4th td element) to each row, and then apply your mousedown. (Note, some editing may be required for syntax/typos)